# Why did God tell David he could not build the temple

Tags: david, temple

Why did God tell David he was not to build the temple?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question as opinion based does not know enough about the narrative in question to be making such decisions. The answer is clearly given in the narrative.

Comment: @Andrew: Which means the question shows no research effort... so that's not a great "defense" of the question, IMO :)

Comment: @Flimzy this is not Stack Overflow, we don't expect people to demonstrate their research and previous attempts in their questions. Even if we did, "opinion based" and "not sure what your asking" do not mean "insufficient research" or "incomplete". The question is not opinion based, and it is clear. Neither is it a duplicate or too broad. So, **if you think it shows lack of effort, downvote**. If it does not fit into a VTC category, then it should remain open.

Comment: @Andrew: haha. Of course we do. That's why the mouse-over text on the down-vote says "This question does not show any research effort."

Comment: @Andrew: This is a poor question, any way you look at it. 1) It asks why God did something, which is [expressly off topic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3983/20). 2) Given your "more charitable" reading of the question, it's might be some sort of a [verse identification](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200/20) question, which is only marginally better. 3) As your answer points out, the answer is found in the same place that would raise the question in the first place, proving the OP did no research. So it's -1, at best, and off-topic on two counts at worst.

Comment: @Flimzy I didn't say it was a good question. I answered because the OP asked it. My interests are  learning, for my benefit and the benefit of those around me, and answering people's questions, for their benefit. Your interested in preserving the standards of this site, I understand that. I'm glad there's a place for both of us here, and I'm glad that the OP got an answer.

Comment: @Flimzy you are not wrong in what you say.  However, it does demonstrate the superiority complex of many here.  You said at best it is a -1.  So why isn't it a -1 and open?  What is wrong with mods and others providing a best effort to facilitate building a community rather than building walls around the community that is already here?  I only use the phrase 'best effort' in union with your 'at best' comment.  I don't mean in any way to diminish the work and effort you all put into this.  I respect that and want to make it better if I can.

Comment: @AdamHeeg: Your comment feels like a Gish Gallop. I'll try to respond to each of your points nonetheless. 1) If I'm right, I don't know why this is even a discussion. 2) I'm not sure what you think demonstrates a superiority complex. I pointed out the flaw in Andrew's logic, when he arrogantly accused multiple members of the community of ignorance. Maybe you meant Andrew was demonstrating a superiority complex? I might agree with that, but I wouldn't use those terms. I don't think that was your point, though... so I guess you'll need to clarify if you want your statement to be meaningful.

Comment: 3) "At best" means it's the best possible outcome. The best possible outcome is rarely the actual outcome--especially in a democracy, or pseudo-democracy like this one. Moreover, I don't know why you're asking *me* why 4 other people voted to close, and one other person downvoted. 4) I don't think anyone said there was anything wrong with mods and others facilitating a community. I think they do apretty good job of that, actually. That doesn't make this question on-topic, and it doesn't make it inappropriate to defend the close/down votes against Andrew's arrogant and ignorant reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

God told David he was not to build him his temple because he had waged wars, and had killed many men. God revealed to David that his son Solomon, a man of peace, should build the temple instead.

> 1 Chronicles 22:5-10 KJV And David said, Solomon my son is young and tender, and the house that is to be builded for the LORD must be exceeding magnifical, of fame and of glory throughout all countries: I will therefore now make preparation for it. So David prepared abundantly before his death.
>
> Then he called for Solomon his son, and charged him to build an house for the LORD God of Israel.
>
> And David said to Solomon, My son, as for me, it was in my mind to build an house unto the name of the LORD my God:
>
> **But the word of the LORD came to me, saying, Thou hast shed blood abundantly, and hast made great wars: thou shalt not build an house unto my name, because thou hast shed much blood upon the earth in my sight.**
>
> Behold, a son shall be born to thee, who shall be a man of rest; and I will give him rest from all his enemies round about: for his name shall be Solomon, and I will give peace and quietness unto Israel in his days.
>
> He shall build an house for my name; and he shall be my son, and I will be his father; and I will establish the throne of his kingdom over Israel for ever.

Comment: I would add that God was also testing David. As a result of this trial, David showed his true heart. When Saul was disciplined, he rebelled against God. When David was told "No", he began gathering materials in preparation for the building of the temple. If he could not build it, he would assist in another way, thus showing his heart for God, and humility. In this way, he is imitating Moses, who when told that he could not enter the promised land because of a mistake made in anger, continued to lead the people and worship God, ensuring that the next generation could enter into it.